# Convertir Objeto a lista

Tags: java, jhipster

**Un poco de contexto**

Estoy haciendo una app en Jhipster al momento crear mi entidad Areas y Usuarios cree una relación ManyToMany que estoy tratando de cargar en ambos lados, para que se puedan asignar areas desde usuarios y usuarios desde areas.

**El problema**

Estoy tratando de convertir un objeto que trae un grupo de usuarios en una lista de la misma clase

```
AreaDTO{id=1351, nombre='Operaciones', mision='Mision', vision='Vision', valores='Valores', politicaCalidad='pollitica de calidad', credo='credo', principios='ssd', usuarios='[ExtendedUserDTO{id=1001, puesto='Desarrollador Web', sueldo=null, fechaIngreso='2019-01-01', usuario=1001, coordinador='system'}, ExtendedUserDTO{id=1251, puesto='null', sueldo=null, fechaIngreso='null', usuario=1251, coordinador='null'}]', desarrollo=1101}
```

El objeto es usuarios y necesito convertidlo a un `List<ExtendedUserDTO>`

Para poder actualizar mi entidad Area.

En Get de mi Areas resource ya lo convierto para poder cargador los datos

```
 /**
     * GET  /areas/:id : get the "id" area.
     *
     * @param id the id of the areaDTO to retrieve
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the areaDTO, or with status 404 (Not Found)
     */
    @GetMapping("/areas/{id}")
    @Timed
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public ResponseEntity<AreaDTO> getArea(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Area : {}", id);
        Optional<AreaDTO> areaDTO = areaService.findOne(id);
        List<ExtendedUser> extendedUserList = extendedUserRepository.findAllByArea(id);
        List<ExtendedUserDTO> extendedUserDTOList = extendedUserList.stream().map(extendedUser -> new ExtendedUserDTO(extendedUser.getUsuario())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        AreaDTO area = areaDTO.get();
        area.setUsuarios(extendedUserDTOList);
        log.debug("Debug de variable areas : {}", extendedUserList);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(area);
    }
```

El AreaDTO

```
package com.gits.sigem.service.dto;

import com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A DTO for the Area entity.
 */
public class AreaDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

    private String mision;

    private String vision;

    private String valores;

    private String politicaCalidad;

    private String credo;

    private String principios;

    private Long desarrolloId;

    private List<ExtendedUserDTO> usuarios;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getMision() {
        return mision;
    }

    public void setMision(String mision) {
        this.mision = mision;
    }

    public String getVision() {
        return vision;
    }

    public void setVision(String vision) {
        this.vision = vision;
    }

    public String getValores() {
        return valores;
    }

    public void setValores(String valores) {
        this.valores = valores;
    }

    public String getPoliticaCalidad() {
        return politicaCalidad;
    }

    public void setPoliticaCalidad(String politicaCalidad) {
        this.politicaCalidad = politicaCalidad;
    }

    public String getCredo() {
        return credo;
    }

    public void setCredo(String credo) {
        this.credo = credo;
    }

    public String getPrincipios() {
        return principios;
    }

    public void setPrincipios(String principios) {
        this.principios = principios;
    }

    public Long getDesarrolloId() {
        return desarrolloId;
    }

    public void setDesarrolloId(Long desarrolloId) {
        this.desarrolloId = desarrolloId;
    }

    public List<ExtendedUserDTO> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }

    public void setUsuarios(List<ExtendedUserDTO> usuarios) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        AreaDTO areaDTO = (AreaDTO) o;
        if (areaDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), areaDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AreaDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", nombre='" + getNombre() + "'" +
            ", mision='" + getMision() + "'" +
            ", vision='" + getVision() + "'" +
            ", valores='" + getValores() + "'" +
            ", politicaCalidad='" + getPoliticaCalidad() + "'" +
            ", credo='" + getCredo() + "'" +
            ", principios='" + getPrincipios() + "'" +
            ", usuarios='" + getUsuarios() + "'" +
            ", desarrollo=" + getDesarrolloId() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

ExtendedUserDTO

```
package com.gits.sigem.service.dto;

import com.gits.sigem.domain.User;
import com.gits.sigem.domain.Area;
import com.gits.sigem.domain.Desarrollo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

/**
 * A DTO for the ExtendedUser entity.
 */
public class ExtendedUserDTO extends UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtendedUserDTO.class);
    private Long id;

    private String puesto;

    private BigDecimal sueldo;

    private LocalDate fechaIngreso;

    private Long usuarioId;

    private Set<Area> areas = new HashSet<>();

    private Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos = new HashSet<>();

    private Long coordinadorId;

    private String coordinadorLogin;

    public ExtendedUserDTO(){

    }

    public ExtendedUserDTO(User user){
        super(user);
        this.puesto = user.getExtendedUser().getPuesto();
        this.sueldo = user.getExtendedUser().getSueldo();
        this.fechaIngreso = user.getExtendedUser().getFechaIngreso();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.usuarioId = user.getId();
        this.coordinadorLogin = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getLogin();
        this.coordinadorId = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getId();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getAreas());
        this.areas = user.getExtendedUser().getAreas();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos());
        this.desarrollos = user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos();
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

    public void setSueldo(BigDecimal sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaIngreso() {
        return fechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setFechaIngreso(LocalDate fechaIngreso) {
        this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    }

    public Long getUsuarioId() {
        return usuarioId;
    }

    public void setUsuarioId(Long userId) {
        this.usuarioId = userId;
    }

    public Set<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Set<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    public Set<Desarrollo> getDesarrollos() {
        return desarrollos;
    }

    public void setDesarrollos(Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos) {
        this.desarrollos = desarrollos;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public String getCoordinadorLogin() {
        return coordinadorLogin;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.coordinadorLogin = userLogin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        ExtendedUserDTO extendedUserDTO = (ExtendedUserDTO) o;
        if (extendedUserDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), extendedUserDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExtendedUserDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", puesto='" + getPuesto() + "'" +
            ", sueldo=" + getSueldo() +
            ", fechaIngreso='" + getFechaIngreso() + "'" +
            ", usuario=" + getUsuarioId() +
            ", coordinador='" + getCoordinadorLogin() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Ahora necesito actualizarlo, el problema es que los datos no vienen como `List<ExtendedUserDTO>` si no como un objeto con varios ExtendedUserDTO.

```
introducir el código aquí
```

**Preguntas**

- ¿Como puedo convertir el objeto a un listado?
- ¿Seria mejor traer    desde angular los usuarios ya como un listado,
  si ese el caso como    convierto desde el userService a un listado?

**Notas**

- Estoy comenzando con Java y Jhipster si necesitan más información o
  no incluí el código necesario dímelo en los comentarios para
  añadirlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de ExtendedUserDTO y de AreaDTO, aunque no entiendo por qué no puedes simplemente hacer `area.getUsuarios()`

Comment: @PabloLozano listo ya los añadi